Unable to get search list selected item id in SwiftUI
I have one api for showing All list and another API for showing search word List but here from all list i am getting selectedDataID but from search list selected item not getting selectedDataID. how to get there as well
code: with this code i am able to show list and able to show search word list as well but while searching if i click on any cell in list then it gives nil in selectedDataID but i can go to SentAndInboxChatView why? how to get selectedDataID in search list as well
struct MessageListView: View {
@StateObject private var viewModel = AllMessagesListViewModel()

@State private var selectedDataID: String?

@State var id: String = ""
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.hexF4F4FC
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
      
            List {
                if viewModel.allMesgs.isEmpty {
                    Text("No records found")
                }else{
                    ForEach(0..<viewModel.allMesgs.count, id: \.self) { ind in
                        
                        Button {
                            selectedDataID = viewModel.allMesgs[ind].id
                            gotoChat = true
                        } label: {
                            messageView(user: viewModel.allMesgs[ind])
                        }
                        if ind == viewModel.allMesgs.count - 1 {
                            Spacer(minLength: 30)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                }
                
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $gotoChat) {
                SentAndInboxChatView(idInbox: selectedDataID ?? "", messageType: MessageType.Inbox.rawValue)
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchAllMessages(id: id) { status in
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}

private var searchFieldView: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding(.leading, 6)
            TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
        
                .onChange(of: searchText) { newValue in
                    if newValue.count >= 3 {
                        viewModel.fetchAllMessagesSearch(id: id, Query: newValue, showHud: false) { status in
                        }

                        print("selectedDataID.... \(selectedDataID) ")

                    }
                    else{
                        viewModel.fetchAllMessages(id: id, showHud: false) { status in
                        }
                    }
                }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                searchText = ""
                viewModel.fetchAllMessages(id: id) { status in
                }
                showingSearchField = false
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(8)
            }
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
    }
}
}

o/p:

selectedDataID.... nil

these are my two API service calls in AllMessagesListViewModel
@MainActor class AllMessagesListViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var allMesgs: [AllMessage] = []
@Published var senderDtl: SenderDTL?

func fetchAllMessages(id: String, showHud: Bool = true, _ completion: @escaping StatusCompletion) {
    
    if APIManager.shared.isConnectedToInternet {
        let url = APIEndPoint.messageFrom
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "ID": id
        ]
        APIManager.shared.callDecodableApiRequest(with: url, method: .get, params: params, showHud: showHud) { (statusCode, error, model: AllMessagesModel?) in
            
            if statusCode.isSuccess {
                self.senderDtl = model?.senderDTL
                 self.allMesgs = model?.allMessages ?? []
                completion(true)
            } else {
                showErrorToast(message: K.Msgs.error)
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    } else {
        showInfoToast(message: K.Msgs.noInternet)
        completion(false)
    }
}

func fetchAllMessagesSearch(id: String, Query: String, showHud: Bool = true, _ completion: @escaping StatusCompletion) {
    
    if APIManager.shared.isConnectedToInternet {
        let url = APIEndPoint.messageFromSearch
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "ID": id,
            "Query": Query
        ]
        APIManager.shared.callDecodableApiRequest(with: url, method: .get, params: params, showHud: showHud) { (statusCode, error, model: AllMessagesModel?) in
            
            if statusCode.isSuccess {
                self.senderDtl = model?.senderDTL
                 self.allMesgs = model?.allMessages ?? []
                completion(true)
            } else {
                showErrorToast(message: K.Msgs.error)
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    } else {
        showInfoToast(message: K.Msgs.noInternet)
        completion(false)
    }
}
}


Did you consider using List(selection:)?

@JoakimDanielson, no i have no idea on it. could you explain it please

Probably better to read the documentation

@JoakimDanielson, i dont need multiple items. i just want selected item id while searching

The documentation mentions that too

ForEach is not a for loop you need to give it the struct array and tell it the keypath to the unique identifer property. You can transform the data before you pass it in if you like.

You could try this alternative approach, using ForEach without the range and index,
using a NavigationLink instead of the Button, and using a different
navigationDestination, such as:
 List {
     if viewModel.allMesgs.isEmpty {
         Text("No records found")
     } else {
         ForEach(viewModel.allMesgs) { msg in
             NavigationLink(value: msg.id) {
                 messageView(user: msg)
             } 
             .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {  // <--- here
                selectedDataID = msg.id
              })

             if viewModel.allMesgs.last == msg {
                 Spacer(minLength: 30)
             }
         }
         .padding(.top, 10)
     }
 }
 .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { itemId in
     SentAndInboxChatView(idInbox: itemId, messageType: MessageType.Inbox.rawValue)
             .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
 }

Note, you can also add .simultaneousGesture to capture the selectedDataID,
see the updated code above.
EDIT-1:
You can also use a Button that records your selectedDataID, such as this approach:
@State private var path = NavigationPath()
 @State private var selectedDataID: String?
 
 NavigationStack(path: $path)
 
 // ...
 List {
     if viewModel.allMesgs.isEmpty {
         Text("No records found")
     } else {
         ForEach(viewModel.allMesgs) { msg in
             Button(action: {
                 selectedDataID = msg.id  // <--- here
                 path.append(msg.id)
             }) {
                 messageView(user: msg)
             }
             if viewModel.allMesgs.last == msg {
                 Spacer(minLength: 30)
             }
         }
         .padding(.top, 10)
     }
 }
 .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { itemId in
     SentAndInboxChatView(idInbox: itemId, messageType: MessageType.Inbox.rawValue)
             .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
 }
 


id: \.self

total navigation is not working with this code.. i have just given like this ForEach(viewModel.allMesgs, id: \.id) { msg in  bcz id: .self this gives error

i want selectedDataID  here if newValue.count >= 3 {

the thing is when i click on list item while searching then how to get selectedDataID  value?? thats the issue

Yes using ForEach(viewModel.allMesgs) is much better if your messages are Identifiable.
I will update my answer. To ...click on list item while searching  then how to get selectedDataID value, see EDIT-1 of my answer. You can then use that in your
if newValue.count >= 3 {...}

no not at all working.
